# Better way to add logging or a method that needs to occur in every function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

Is there a better way to log or add a method calls to a series of functions without explicitly adding in the function calls?

For example I have a class like:

```
public class MyClass
{

public void DoStuff()
{
doSomethingEnter();

//MyCode

doSomethingExit();
}

public void DoStuff_2()
{
doSomethingEnter();

//MyCode

doSomethingExit();
}
}
```

doSomethingEnter() and doSomethingExit() can be logging calls or events calling other things that need to occur on function start and end.

I have read on Aspect Oriented Programming that allows me to do something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{

[DoSomethingEnterExit]
public void DoStuff()
{
   //MyCode
}
}
```

But is there a pattern or framework that allows me to do something similar without having to buy an AOP framework like PostSharp?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I have also looked into doing sort of a facade to make sure stuff always gets  called with a master method that has the entry and exit functions.

```
public class MyFacade
{
  public void MasterMethod(string methodName)
  {
    doSomethingEnter();
    if(methodName == "DoStuff")
    {
      MyClass.DoStuff();
    }
    else
    {
      MyClass.DoStuff_2();
    }
    doSomethingExit();
  }
}
```

Comment: This might be promising: https://github.com/AntyaDev/KingAOP

Comment: You could try a constructor/destructor of a base class.

Comment: @Asmodiel is the exit function guaranteed to run on end of the function? Isn't the destructor dependent on the garbage collection schedule?

Comment: Is there any problem with using attributes? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_attributes.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) to inject logging into your code transparently at compile time.

PostSharp is an AOP library for .Net and it uses reflection Attributes to allow you to put markers (aspects) in your code, then a pre-compiler locates those markers and replaces them with the actual code.

> Disclosure: I'm not affiliated with PostSharp, but have used it before in some of my projects.

Edit:

- As far as I remember, there is still a free and open source version of PostSharp that will work for the logging scenario.
- I haven't heard of other AOP libraries in .Net ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

Castle Windsor offers [interceptors](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md) that will do this for you. If you don't want to use an entire IoC framework just for this, you could go straight to [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) to achieve the same thing. However, having an IoC container handle the wiring is nice and neat.

You could also consider using the [Decorator](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) pattern. However, this often results in significant proliferation of code if the concerns are many.

A drawback to consider when using interception or decoration is that the additional concerns each pattern adds are transparent. This is great for reducing the noise but can be difficult to debug or enhance if those supporting the code are unaware or unfamiliar with the concepts.

An additional drawback, as highlighted by @Bishoy in the comments below, is that these are run-time solutions that may have an impact on performance that the 'static' approaches do not.

Comment: I'd recommend you mention also the performance impact compared to the AOP approach

Comment: @Bishoy what are your specific concerns? It's not something I can comment on with any degree of detail.

Comment: Compile time (static) vs run time (dynamic) has a material impact on performance of the application. Dynamic proxy is a dynamic run time solution. The details will be application specific.